# Best way to indicate an event should be fired in a dojo subclass

Tags: javascript, events, inheritance, dojo

I'm designing an abstract superclass in javascript using dojo. The purpose of the class is to define the contract for any UI element that can enable the user to select an entity with a unique identifier. So far this is my code.

```
define(
[   
    "dojo/Evented",
    "dojo/_base/declare"
],
function(Evented, declare){
    var NotImplementedException = "Method not implemented"; 
    return declare("EntitySelector", Evented, {
        //it's implementation should change the entity selected by the UI
        select: function(id){
            throw NotImplementedException;
        },
        //it's implemantation should populate the UI with the data to be selected.
        setData: function(dataStore){
            throw NotImplementedException;
        }

    });
});
```

I also need that subclasses fire an onSelect event, so I can respond to the user actually selecting an entity.

Is there a way (other than documentation) to indicate that subclasses should fire the onSelect event on their implementation?

Fo example, in Java you usually define a `public void addEventListener(ListenerInterface)` method to indicate that subclasses should fire an event. In C# you can declare an `event EventHandler` to achieve something similar.

Is there a way in dojo or general Javascript to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like the code bellow.
It rely on the widget lifecycle provided by _WidgetBase and check whether or not some method are implemented.
Additionally it automatically add the "onSelect" event when the "select" method is fired.
Another approach is to hook on the `on` method and check if an event is attached (see how it is for the `foo` event.

```js
require([
  "dojo/Evented",
  "dojo/aspect",  
  "dijit/_WidgetBase",
  "dojo/_base/lang",
  "dojo/_base/declare"
], function(Evented, aspect, _WidgetBase, lang, declare) {
  var NotImplementedException = "Method not implemented";

  var EntitySelector = declare([_WidgetBase, Evented], {
    hasOnFooEvent: false,
    
    postMixInProperties: function() {

      if (typeof this.select !== 'function') {
        throw NotImplementedException;
      } else {
        this.own(aspect.after(this, 'select', lang.hitch(this, 'emit', 'onSelect')))
      }
      if (typeof this.setData !== 'function') {
        throw NotImplementedException;
      }
      this.inherited(arguments);
    },
    
    on: function(eventName) {
      if(eventName === 'foo') {
        this.hasOnFooEvent = true;
      }
      this.inherited(arguments);
    },
    postCreate: function() {
      if(!this.hasOnFooEvent) {
         throw NotImplementedException;
      }
      this.inherited(arguments);
    }
  });

  var NotOkWidget = declare(EntitySelector, {});

  var OkWidget = declare(EntitySelector, {
    postCreate: function() {
      this.on('foo', function() {});
      this.inherited(arguments);
    },
    select: function() {},
    setData: function() {}
  });
  
  
  try {
    var a = new NotOkWidget();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Implementation error on NotOkWidget');
  }
  try {
    var a = new OkWidget();
    a.on('onSelect', function() { console.log('onSelect event is fired'); });
    a.select();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Implementation error on OkWidget');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```